# How to import CSS/JS files for Laravel Vite Builds

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vite, laravel-vite

This is my current Laravel Vite configuration `vite.config.js`

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import laravel from 'laravel-vite-plugin'
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue2'

export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [
        vue(),
        laravel({
            input: ['resources/sass/_top/top.scss'],
            refresh: true
        })
    ],
    server: {
        port: 3500
    },
    resolve: {
        alias: {
            vue: 'vue/dist/vue.esm.js'
        }
    }
})
```

The input file generates a file at `public/build/assets/top.d0g7acf3.css`. How do I use this file at my blade file without explicitly using the string `d0g7acf3` which changes every build?

Of course this works in my blade file :

```
<!-- more html codes -->
@vite('build/assets/top.d0d7acf2.css')
<!-- more html codes -->
```

These don't work:

- `@vite('build/assets/top.css')`
- `@vite('resources/sass/_top/top.scss')`

Comment: Did you try `@vite('resources/sass/_top/top.css')` ?

Comment: @bassxzero yes, I have tried both `@vite('resources/sass/_top/top.scss')` and `@vite('build/assets/top.css')`

Comment: What is the problem? Does something not work after building your assets? vite should take care of everything

Comment: @brombeer Maybe because I am using `Vue2` and `@vitejs/plugin-vue2`. The generated file is `public/build/assets/top.aae5b5a6.css`. If I call just `@vite('resources/sass/_top/top.css')` the html generated is `<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://127.0.0.1:3500/css/_top/top.css" />` which is broken of course. Only the `@vite('build/assets/top.aae5b5a6.css')` works.

Comment: You still haven't stated what the problem is, do styles not get loaded? You basically use `@vite('resources/sass/_top/top.scss')` in your blade to load your assets, no matter if you `npm run dev` or `npm run build` - vite will know what asset to load, nothing else required on your side

Comment: @brombeer When I use `@vite('resources/sass/_top/top.scss')` in my blade, the css will be broken because it generates in the html `<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://127.0.0.1:3500/css/_top/top.css" />` no matter if it is from `npm run dev` or `npm run build`

Answer (score 0):

In Laravel Vite, you can use the `@vite` directive in your Blade templates to include the generated CSS and JS files. The `@vite` directive automatically handles the hashed filenames for you.

However, you should not include the file extension when using the `@vite` directive. So instead of `@vite('build/assets/top.css')`, you should use `@vite('build/assets/top')`.

Here's how you can include the generated CSS file in your Blade template:

```html
<!-- more html codes -->
@vite('build/assets/top')
<!-- more html codes -->
```

This will include the correct CSS file, even if the filename changes with each build due to hashing.